# How do you unittest exceptions in Dart?

Tags: dart

Consider a function that does some exception handling based on the arguments passed:

```dart
List range(start, stop) {
    if (start >= stop) {
      throw new ArgumentError("start must be less than stop");
    }
    // remainder of function
}
```

How do I test that the right kind of exception is raised?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

In this case, there are various ways to test the exception. To simply test that an unspecific exception is raised:

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 5), throwsException);
```

to test that the right type of exception is raised:

there are several predefined matchers for general purposes like `throwsArgumentError`, `throwsRangeError`, `throwsUnsupportedError`, etc.. for types for which no predefined matcher exists, you can use `TypeMatcher<T>`.

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 2), throwsA(TypeMatcher<IndexError>()));
```

to ensure that no exception is raised:

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 10), returnsNormally);
```

to test the exception type and exception message:

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 3), 
    throwsA(predicate((e) => e is ArgumentError && e.message == 'start must be less than stop')));
```

here is another way to do this:

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 3), 
  throwsA(allOf(isArgumentError, predicate((e) => e.message == 'start must be less than stop'))));
```

(Thanks to Graham Wheeler at Google for the last 2 solutions).

Comment: I was doing `expect(range(5, 3), throwsArgumentError)`, but the exception was not catched inside the expect. The first argument to expect must be an anonymous function that will eventually throw when called. Your answer helped me to find that stupid error, thanks!

Comment: meanwhile `new isInstanceOf<ArgumentError>()` is deprecated. TypeMatcher should be used instead: `throwsA(TypeMatcher<Exception>())` for instance

Comment: It seems using TypeMatcher no longer works. What works is `throwsA(isA<Exception>())`

Comment: This is definitely the best answer but I wonder why the syntax has to be so verbose for such a simple task..

Comment: You cannot do without the closure for the test, but if you need this many time consider creating a custom matcher for more terse code.

Comment: This works with constructors as well which have arguments

Answer (score 20):

I like this approach:

```
test('when start > stop', () {
  try {
    range(5, 3);
  } on ArgumentError catch(e) {
    expect(e.message, 'start must be less than stop');
    return;
  }
  throw new ExpectException("Expected ArgumentError");  
});
```

Comment: It's a bit more verbose than the other options, but it's fairly readable, and it doesn't assume you have the entire unittest library memorized ;)

Answer (score 17):

As a more elegant solution to [@Shailen Tuli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638061/shailen-tuli)'s proposal, if you want to expect an error with a specific message, you can use [`having`](https://github.com/dart-lang/matcher/blob/12c97635b73a17c2766397e0aeb07ff9669e889c/lib/src/type_matcher.dart#L82).

In this situation, you are looking for something like this:

```dart
expect(
  () => range(5, 3),
  throwsA(
    isA<ArgumentError>().having(
      (error) => error.message,        // The feature you want to check.
      'message',                       // The description of the feature.
      'start must be less than stop',  // The error message.
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 7):

An exception is checked using [`throwsA`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-test_api_test_api/throwsA.html) with [`TypeMatcher`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/TypeMatcher-class.html).

**Note**: [isInstanceOf](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/isInstanceOf-class.html) is now deprecated.

```
List range(start, stop) {
    if (start >= stop) {
      throw new ArgumentError("start must be less than stop");
    }
    // remainder of function
}


test("check argument error", () {
  expect(() => range(1, 2), throwsA(TypeMatcher<ArgumentError>()));
});
```

Comment: I was missing the () => sintaxe of expect() method. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers are definitely valid, APIs like `TypeMatcher<Type>()` are deprecated now, and you have to use `isA<TypeOfException>()`.

For instance, what was previously,

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 2), throwsA(TypeMatcher<IndexError>()));
```

Will now be

```dart
expect(() => range(5, 2), throwsA(isA<IndexError>()));
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple exception testing, I prefer to use the static method API:

```
Expect.throws(
  // test condition
  (){ 
    throw new Exception('code I expect to throw');
  },
  // exception object inspection
  (err) => err is Exception
);
```

Comment: It did not work with me. Seems Expect.throws() is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following approach:

First you need to pass in your method as a lambda into the expect function:

```
expect(() => method(...), ...)
```

Secondly you need to use `throwsA` in combination with `isInstanceOf`.

`throwsA` makes sure that an exception is thrown, and with `isInstanceOf` you can check if the correct Exception was thrown.

Example for my unit test:

```
expect(() => parser.parse(raw), throwsA(isInstanceOf<FailedCRCCheck>()));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people try doing things like:

```dart
void f() => throw Exception();

expect(f(), throwsException); // WRONG
```

or

```dart
expect(f(), throwsA(isA<Exception>())); // WRONG
```

and then when they go and run their test, their test fails from an uncaught `Exception` instead of that exception being being caught and matched.

The reason *why* this happens is because `expect()` is an ordinary function.  Dart, like most other programming languages, is an [*applicative-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order) language, which means that it evaluates function arguments *before* invoking the function.  Therefore `f()` is called and throws an exception before `expect()` is called and has an opportunity to match against the `throwsException` or `throwsA` `Matchers`.  To match an exception thrown by `f()`, you cannot call `f()` directly and must delay its execution with a [*thunk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk).

As explained by the [`throwsA`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test/latest/test/throwsA.html) documentation (and this applies to the `throwsException` `Matcher` too), it must be matched against a zero-argument function or a `Future`.