# Flutter: Test that a specific exception is thrown

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

in short, `throwsA(anything)` does not suffice for me while unit testing in dart. How to I test for a **specific error message or type**?

Here is the error I would like to catch:

```
class MyCustErr implements Exception {
  String term;

  String errMsg() => 'You have already added a container with the id 
  $term. Duplicates are not allowed';

  MyCustErr({this.term});
}
```

here is the current assertion that passes, but would like to check for the error type above:

`expect(() => operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(anything));`

This is what I want to do:

`expect(() => operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(MyCustErr));`

Comment: You can check out this post for answers on how to match for specific messages as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298969/how-do-you-unittest-exceptions-in-dart

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
expect(() => operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(isA<MyCustErr>()));
```

if you just want to check for exception check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13299055/563848):

Comment: there's a `instanceOf ` matcher too.

Comment: Right, that's a shorthand

Comment: That did not work for me. maybe due to my setup however: ```Expected: <Instance of 'MyCustErr'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => dynamic>```

removing the closure does not work either

Comment: throwsA method works fine. I tried the isInstanceOf first

Comment: nossir it did not for me but so long as I have an alternative. thank you!

Comment: As a note to future people, I wasn't able to get the first alternative to work. I discovered it was because VS Code Intellisense had me import `'package:flutter/{widgets-material-cupertino}.dart'` when you actually want to import `'package:matcher/matcher.dart'`.

Comment: @Abion47, removing import for wrong package `'package:flutter/{widgets-material-cupertino}.dart'` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: The TypeMatcher<> is deprecated in Flutter 1.12.1 onwards.
For me, this matcher works: `throwsA(isInstanceOf<MyCustErr>())`

Comment: Both `TypeMatcher` and `isInstanceOf` have been deprecated. Use `throwsA(isA<MyCustErr>())` instead.

Comment: 10/10 made it like `expect(() => mapper.reverseMap(entity)), throwsUnimplementedError);`

Answer (score 38):

As of April 2021 this is the correct method.

CORRECT METHOD

```
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

 /// GOOD: works in all circumstances.
 expect(() => restoreFile(file), throwsA(isA<RestoreFileException>()));
```

Some examples show :

INCORRECT METHOD

```
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
 /// BAD: works but not in all circumstances
 expect(restoreFile(file), throwsA(isA<RestoreFileException>()));
```

Note the missing '() => ' after the expect.

The difference is that the first method will work for functions that return void whilst the second method won't.

So the first method should be the prefered technique.

To test for a specific error message:

CHECK CONTENTS OF EXCEPTION AS WELL

```
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

    expect(
        () => copy(from, to),
        throwsA(predicate((e) =>
            e is CopyException &&
            e.message == 'The from file ${truepath(from)} does not exists.')));
```

Comment: This certainly works but there's no logical reason why should one pass lambdas for it to work! This is straight-up unintuitive syntax comparing to something like JUnit.

Comment: @Arrow if the method being called returns null then you must use () otherwise you get a compile error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. ... I do have lints turned up to 11 which might be why you see a difference.

Answer (score 17):

After `TypeMatcher<>' has been deprecated in Flutter 1.12.1 I found this to work:

```
expect(() => operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(isInstanceOf<MyCustErr>()));
```

Comment: `isInstanceOf` has been deprecated as well, in favor of `isA`. So the code should now be `expect(() => operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(isA<MyCustErr>()));`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to test with an async function like I had to do all you need to do is add `async` keyword in the expect, bearing in mind that the `lookupOrderDetails` is an async function:

```
expect(() **async** => **await** operations.lookupOrderDetails(), throwsA(const TypeMatcher<MyCustErr>()));

expect(() **async** => **await** operations.lookupOrderDetails(), isInstanceOf<MyCustErr>()));
```

It still uses Gunter's answer which is very good!

Comment: Not sure why, but neither of those variants worked for me, however `expect(() async => await resultFuture, throwsA(isInstanceOf<MyCustErr>()));` did

Answer (score 1):

First import correct package **'package:matcher/matcher.dart'**;

```
expect(() => yourOperation.yourMethod(),
      throwsA(const TypeMatcher<YourException>()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The current proper way to expect that a function call throws an exception is:

```
expect(operations.lookupOrderDetails, throwsA(isA<MyCustErr>()));`
```