# How to test for exceptions in test_driver?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

#### Widget tests

I know that I can `expect` exceptions in **widget tests**:

- [Flutter: Testing for exceptions in widget tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54262024/6509751)
- [Flutter: Test that a specific exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54241396/6509751)

However, I want to test for an `Error` or an `Exception` when running my app using [`flutter_driver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/flutter_driver-library.html).

### Integration tests

Currently, I simply look at the logs when running `test_driver` and check if the logged exceptions are what I expect. However, that is not ideal and I want to integrate the exceptions into the rest of the integration testing.

#### flutterDriverLog

I found [`flutterDriverLog` in the `flutter_driver` library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/flutterDriverLog.html), however, the exceptions do not appear there. It only sends records for the `FlutterDriver` status, e.g.:

```
[info ] FlutterDriver: Connecting to Flutter application at ..
[trace] FlutterDriver: Isolate found with number: ..
...
```

#### What I am looking for

I would love to have some code like this:

```dart
group('Some tests', () {
  test('Button that throws an exception', () async {
    await flutterDriver.tap(find.byType(IconButton));

    // The following property and function do not exist.
    expect(thatExceptionIsThrown, thatMatches('PlatformException(some_error'));
  });
});
```

How do I do that when running `FlutterDriver`?

Comment: Does it even make sense in integration tests? That's an implementation detail and you'd likely want to test that the error page is shown

Comment: @RémiRousselet The `PlatformException` can only occur in integration tests, but I want to make sure that it is thrown because otherwise the integration test will have failed to execute a certain task.

Comment: Can't you instead that that the "certain task" succeeded?

Comment: @RémiRousselet The exception is the best indicator. There is also a visual indicator, but testing for that is almost impossible with `FlutterDriver` and requires restructuring the app itself. However, I do not want to build an app about its integration tests. It should be the other way round.