# How do I test an assertion?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I found out how you can test an exception or error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54241438/6509751

But how do I test that the following `assert` works correctly?

```dart
void cannotBeNull(dynamic param) {
  assert(param != null);
}
```

I tried the following, but it does not work. The assertion is simply printed out and the test fails:

```dart
void main() {
  test('cannoBeNull assertion', () {
    expect(cannotBeNull(null), throwsA(const TypeMatcher<AssertionError>()));
  });
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39305

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two key aspects to this:

- Pass a callback to `expect`. When you do that, you can never do something wrong, even if you just instantiate an object. This was already shown [in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54241438/6509751).
- Use [`throwAssertionError`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/throwsAssertionError.html).
- If you are using pure Dart and not Flutter you can use `throwsA(isA<AssertionError>())`

Example:

```dart
expect(() {
  assert(false);
}, throwsAssertionError);
```

or

```dart
expect(() {
  assert(false);
}, throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
```

Applied to the code from the question:

```dart
void main() {
  test('cannoBeNull assertion', () {
    expect(() => cannotBeNull(null), throwsAssertionError);
  });
}
```

or

```dart
void main() {
  test('cannoBeNull assertion', () {
    expect(() => cannotBeNull(null), throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
  });
}
```

---

Why do we need to pass a callback? Well, if you have a function without parameters, you can also pass a *reference* to that as well.

If there was no callback, the assertion would be evaluated before `expect` is executed and there would be no way for `expect` to catch the error. By passing a callback, we allow `expect` to call that callback, which allows it to catch the `AssertionError` and it is able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

*Applied to the code from the question*(This is exactly what worked for me, used  **throwsA(TypeMatcher()** instead of the **throwsAssertionError**):

```dart
void main() {
  test('cannoBeNull assertion', () {
    expect(() => cannotBeNull(null), throwsA(TypeMatcher<AssertionError>()));
  });
}
```