# How do you test if an exception is thrown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I seem to be unable to test if an exception is thrown in Flutter. I would expect the test to pass if an exception is thrown considering I expect an Exception.

What I have tried:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Range error test', () {
    expect(throw RangeError(""), throwsA(RangeError("")));
  });
  test('Range error test', () {
    expect(throw RangeError(""), throwsA(RangeError));
  });

  test('Range error test', () {
    expect(throw RangeError(""), throwsRangeError);
  });

  test('ConcurrentModificationError error test', () {
    expect(throw ConcurrentModificationError(""), throwsA(ConcurrentModificationError));
  });

  test('NumberFormat error test', () {
    expect(int.parse("sdffg"), throwsA(FormatException));
  });

  test('NumberFormat error test', () {
    expect(int.parse("sdffg"), throwsFormatException);
  });

  test('Range error test', () {
    var list = [];
    expect(list[1], throwsRangeError);
  });

  test('Range error test', () {
    var list = [];
    expect(list[1], throwsA(RangeError));
  });
}
```

dependencies in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test:
```

Errors after running them in Android Studio (I get the same errors when running from cli):
[image: errors]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take one of your examples:

```dart
expect(throw RangeError(""), throwsA(RangeError("")));
```

There are a few problems here.

Since `throw RangeError("")` is part of a larger expression, it is evaluated before the whole expression does, so you can't hope for `expect()` to be evaluated if `throw RangeError("")` breaks the flow.

To make this explanation more didactic, imagine we extracted the arguments into variables:

```dart
final neverAssigned = throw RangeError("");
final throwsRangeError = throwsA(RangeError(""));
expect(neverAssigned, throwsRangeError);
```

As you may have realized, we never reach `expect()` because the program already throws at the first line.

To solve this problem, `expect()` requires you to pass a function that potentially throws. It will check that it is a function, wrap the call in try-catch and check whether the error thrown is what you expect.

We should end up with something like this:

```dart
expect(() => throw RangeError(""), throwsA(RangeError("")));
```

However, this doesn't work as well, since errors in general don't implement `operator ==` and `hashCode`, so `RangeError("") == RangeError("")` gives you `false`. This means it's not that simple to check whether the error thrown is exactly what you expect.

Instead, you should check only the type with something like `throwsA(isA<RangeError>())`, or [check the message with `having`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288447/6696558).