# Test error while handling of null-aware operation '!'

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, exception

I am writing a test case for the null-aware operation '!', but not able to catch the exception.

**Function:**

```
 int? notNullAssertionForException() {
    String? country;
    return country!.length;
  }
```

**Test:**

```
test('Not Null Assertion For Exception Test', () {
    final nullSafety = NullSafety();
    expect(nullSafety.notNullAssertionForException(), null);
  });
```

**Error:** Null check operator used on a null value

I am not able to figure out the way to test this. How I can pass this test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you unittest exceptions in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298969/how-do-you-unittest-exceptions-in-dart)

Comment: @jamesdlin: But in my case, I am not getting any exception to catch, it would be great if you give an answer above, Thanks!!

Comment: As explained by the linked answer, you must test for a exceptions by passing a *function* to `expect()`.  Otherwise it will throw an exception immediately before `expect` is even called. `expect(notNullAssertionForException, throwsA(isA<CastError>()));` works fine.

Comment: expect(() => nullSafety.notNullAssertionForException(), throwsA(isA<TypeError>())); this working